# How to Go About Limiting Memory Usage, Java's Groovy Executor

Tags: java, groovy

In using the Groovy executor for Java, I need to limit the script execution time and the memory size of the variables in the groovy objects.
Here is my part code,The groovy object here is groovy.lang.GroovyObject

```
        final ImportCustomizer imports = new ImportCustomizer();
        imports.addImports(concatArrays(DEFAULT_IMPORTS, importClasses));
        imports.addStarImports(concatArrays(DEFAULT_STAR_IMPORTS, starImports));

        final SecureASTCustomizer secure = new SecureASTCustomizer();
        secure.setClosuresAllowed(true);
        secure.setIndirectImportCheckEnabled(true);

        secure.setTokensBlacklist(concatList(new Integer[0], TOKEN_BLACK_LIST));

        final CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration();
        config.addCompilationCustomizers(imports, secure);
        if (maxCpuTime > 0) {
            config.addCompilationCustomizers(new ASTTransformationCustomizer(Collections.singletonMap("value", maxCpuTime), TimedInterrupt.class));
        }
        config.addCompilationCustomizers(new SandboxTransformer());
        new SandboxInterceptor().register();

        loader = new GroovyClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), config);
        Class<?> clazz = loader.parseClass(scriptBuilder.toString());
        groovy = (GroovyObject) clazz.newInstance();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> prop : scriptProperties.entrySet()) {
            groovy.setProperty(prop.getKey(), prop.getValue());
        }
```

The maven dependencies I referenced are as follows:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kohsuke</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-sandbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
```

I can use the included annotations to limit the runtime of the script, but I don't know how to limit the memory.I put external custom variables into the script via 'groovy.setProperty(prop.getKey(), prop.getValue());' and the script runs to set the value, even an infinite loop to set values.

What I want is to just terminate the script when the memory reaches a specified threshold, just like the 'TimedInterrupt' annotation above, and when the specified time is exceeded, it will 'TimeoutException'.

Comment: "I can use the included annotations to limit the runtime of the script" to which annotations are your referring? Provide the example in your code. Note that the page for the [groovy-sandbox source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/groovy-sandbox) says it is deprecated, it is insecure and should not be used. Not sure how are you using because your code misses the imports. Provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I only use 'groovy-sandbox ' to do some code-level restrictions, such as restricting the file manipulation class 'java.io.File' to irrelevant time restrictions.
The time restriction annotation I'm talking about is reflected in this code 'config.addCompilationCustomizers(new ASTTransformationCustomizer(Collections.singletonMap("value", maxCpuTime), TimedInterrupt.class));', the sample code has.
The annotation is 'groovy.transform.TimedInterrupt'.

Comment: Please add the details to the question.

Comment: Here is my sample code 'public class GroovyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
        String groovy = " def call(int a,int b) { " +
                "   return a + b " +
                "}";
 
        GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader();
        Class scriptClass = loader.parseClass(groovy);
        GroovyObject scriptInstance = (GroovyObject)         scriptClass.newInstance();
        result = scriptInstance.invokeMethod("call",new Object[] {1,2});
        System.out.println("Groovy result=" + result);
    }
}',

Comment: Close the script if it uses too much memory while it is running.Calling methods may result in a high memory footprint due to the script code written